# loading module mod_perl into apache 2.2 64 bit

Tags: mod-perl, apache2.2

Every time I am loading mod_perl into apache2.2, 64 bit and doing Test Configuration: The following error occurs

"httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 129 of C:/Program Files/Apache
Software Foundati
on/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache
Software Found
ation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_perl.so into server: The specified module
could not
be found.
Note the errors or messages above, and press the  key to exit.
27..."

Please guys .. Help me out of this...?

I already installed Strawberry perl(64 bit) on my system.

Answer (score -1):

I want to see your httpd.conf.

I think that your httpd.conf's line 129 is `LoadModule ...mod_perl.so`.
But your environment does not have `C:/Program Files/Apache Software Found ation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_perl.so` file, or its read permission.

Please check above points.